# Regex for password must contain exactly one uppercase character

Tags: regex, passwords

I want a regular expression to check that:

A password contains exactly one uppercase character, includes at least one special character (`#, @, -`) and password length must be at least 8 symbols!

```
(?=.[A-Z]{1}?)(?=.*[#@-])[A-Za-z#@-]{8,}
```

How can I write it for a password contains **exactly** one uppercase character?

Comment: Before doing this, you should read https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/are-password-complexity-rules-counterproductive and consider whether it actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)(?=.*[#@-])[A-Za-z#@-]{8,}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Fr6znT/1

Breakdown:

- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)` at the position it is means: *"The whole expression should be 'any number of non uppercase chars', followed by 'one uppercase char', followed by 'any number of non uppercase chars'"*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?=(?=.*[@#-]{1,})[\S]{8,})([a-z@#-]*[@#-]*[A-Z][a-z@#-]*[@#-]*)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/v8Erhu/1